# How to show all column with min statement?

Tags: t-sql

so I want to get the minimal of a table without using the top statement. I came up with this

```
select min(deathdate) from players
```

but the flaw of this is that it only shows one column. I want all the columns as if

```
select * from players
```

So how do I combine an min statement that shows all columns. Hopefully keep it as simple as possible. If not an min statement, how else can I get an top 1 statement without using top 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
select * from players
where deathdate = (select min(deathdate) from players)
```

That's about as simple as you can make it without using `top`.

---

Note that this will not break ties - if 2 people have the same deathdate, both will be returned. To break ties:

```
select *, row_number() over (order by name) rn from players
where deathdate = (select min(deathdate) from players)
and rn = 1
```

Comment: What if you have multiple of same value for deathdate. How can you then select the first alphabetically named player.